# How to create an array within the constructor?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new array as an attribute of the object once I create a new instance. But I get the following error in Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined". Players seems to be unkown. But why?

```
function Team(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Players = new Array();
}

Team.prototype.AddPlayer = new function (player) {
    this.Players.push(player); //error
}
```

Comment: Within what constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the 'new' in this line

```
Team.prototype.AddPlayer = function (player) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you need to be sure to make a new `Team` instance using `new`.

```
var t = new Team("foo");
t.AddPlayer("bar");
```

---

Oops, one error in your code. Remove `new` from before `function` in the `.prototype` assignment.

```
function Team(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Players = new Array();
}

Team.prototype.AddPlayer = /*new*/ function (player) {
    this.Players.push(player);
}
```

Because you had `new` before the function, you were actually using the anonymous function *as a constructor*, which means it was being *invoked*.

To be clear, `new` *does not make a new function* unless it is placed before the `Function` constructor.

Comment: The problem is the `new` keyword on the prototype declaration

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's the first time I'm working with prototypes and "real" objects in JS.